# datagrid doesn't bind with datatable

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm working on a webpage in azure. Here's a part of my code:

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("my connection string"))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Students", conn);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter _adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable ds = new DataTable();
                _adp.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;

                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
```

Off course that instead of "my connection string" there's the real one...

The problem is that the page loads but without the gridview for some reason...

Any help will be great, Thanks

EDIT: I also tried with datasets, like this:

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("my connection string"))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Students", conn);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter _adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                _adp.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
```

Comment: any exception? tried putting debugger?

Comment: you have said you tried dataset, did you follow first reading to dataset and then assigning table to gridview ?

Comment: @KbManu I just found something out...when I reload the page (i did it with a submit button that did just that), the gridview shows properly....

Comment: I am not sure, though it doesn't make sense, just to debug, after you assign to GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; set null, GridView1.DataSource = null; and then call again _adp.Fill(ds), let me know if its same!

Comment: LOL! I just didn't handle the IsPostBack normally....thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with  `GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`

whole code will look as follows:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("my connection string"))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Students", conn);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter _adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataTable();
                _adp.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
```

Comment: 'ds' is not array ! Its not Dataset, its table !

Comment: Just tried that and wanted to say what @KbManu said. any other suggestion?

Comment: just for time being try with datasets..or have a look at values in datatable in your code with quick watch

Comment: have watched the values which are comming in dataset through quickview [ cntrl+Q while you debug the code]??

Comment: I run it on the cloud, how can I debug it?